# Jenkins pipeline - custom timeout behavior

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I need custom behavior for the timeout function. For example, when I use:

```
timeout(time: 10, unit: 'MINUTES') {
    doSomeStuff()        
}
```

it terminates the doSomeStuff() function.

What I want to achieve is not to terminate the execution of the function, but to call another function every 10 minutes until doSomeStuff() is done with executing.
I can't use the Build-timeout Plugin from Jenkins since I need to apply this behavior to pipelines.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has the same issue: After some research, the only way that came to my mind to solve my problem was to modify the [notification plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/notification) for the jenkins pipeline, in a way to add a new field that would contain value of time (in minutes) to delay the invoking of the url. In the code itself, where the url was invoked, i put those lines in a new thread and let that thread sleep for the needed amount of time before executing the remaining code. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onStarted(final Run r, final TaskListener listener) {
    HudsonNotificationProperty property = (HudsonNotificationProperty) r.getParent().getProperty(HudsonNotificationProperty.class);
    int invokeUrlTimeout = 0;
    if (property != null && !property.getEndpoints().isEmpty()){
        invokeUrlTimeout = property.getEndpoints().get(0).getInvokeUrlTimeout();
    }
    int finalInvokeUrlTimeout = invokeUrlTimeout;
    new Thread(() -> {
        sleep(finalInvokeUrlTimeout * 60 * 1000);
        Executor e = r.getExecutor();
        Phase.QUEUED.handle(r, TaskListener.NULL, e != null ? System.currentTimeMillis() - e.getTimeSpentInQueue() : 0L);
        Phase.STARTED.handle(r, listener, r.getTimeInMillis());
    }).start();
}
```

Maybe not the best solution but it works for me, and I hope it helps other people too.